# Sequelize-test-helpers and calledWith AssertionError undefined argument

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I am new to testing with `sinon, chai and mocha`
I am using those three testing libraries and the package `sequelize-test-helpers`

I am trying to run a test to check if the belongsTo association is working correctly here is the step I have taken:

First off here is the actual table from my database I am using sequelize and the DB is Postgres

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  // const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;
  const DealerProduct = sequelize.define('DealerProduct', {
    dpid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    product_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      // validate: {
      //   len: [1, 100]
      // }
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
      allowNull: true,
      // validate: {
      //   len: [1, 100]
      // }
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'dealer_products',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // freezeTableName: true
    // paranoid: true
  });

  DealerProduct.associate = models => { // **For starters this is the belongsTo association I would like to make my test for**
    DealerProduct.belongsTo(models.Dealer, { 
      foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        name: "dealers_did",
      }
    });

    DealerProduct.hasOne(models.StoreProduct, {
      foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'dealer_product_dpid'
      }
    })
  };

  return DealerProduct;
}
```

And here is the test

```
const {
    sequelize,
    dataTypes,
    checkModelName,
    checkPropertyExists,
    checkUniqueIndex
} = require('sequelize-test-helpers');
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai)

const DealerProductModel = require('../../models/dealer-products-model');

describe('server/models/all', async () => {

  describe('server/models/dealer-products-model', async () => {
    
    const DealerProduct = DealerProductModel(sequelize, dataTypes);
    const dealerProduct = new DealerProduct();

    checkModelName(DealerProduct)('DealerProduct');

    describe('check all properties exist', () => {
        ['dpid', 'product_name', 'type', 'description', 'price', 'quantity'].forEach(checkPropertyExists(dealerProduct))
    })

    describe('check associations', () => {
      const OtherModel = 'Dealer' // it doesn't matter what
      before(() => {
        DealerProduct.associate( { OtherModel }  )
      })
      it('defined a belongsTo association with Dealer', () => {
        chai.expect(DealerProduct.belongsTo).to.have.been.calledWith(OtherModel, {
          foreignKey: {
            type: dataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            name: 'dealer_product_dpid'
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })

})
```

I was following this example here from this [page](https://itnext.io/unit-testing-sequelize-models-made-easy-108f079f1e38#7a57)

I have no clue how to link sinon with chai so that the `calledWith` would work but I searched around I found to do it like this as I imported them (probably I am wrong here or missing something):

```
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai)
```

it does some how make the `calledWith` work as I am spying to look at the association from this `expect` method:

```
    describe('check associations', () => {
      const OtherModel = 'Dealer' // it doesn't matter what
      before(() => {
        DealerProduct.associate( { OtherModel }  )
      })
      it('defined a belongsTo association with Dealer', () => {
        chai.expect(DealerProduct.belongsTo).to.have.been.calledWith(OtherModel, {
          foreignKey: {
            type: dataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            name: 'dealer_product_dpid'
          }
        })
      })
    })
```

I am getting this error:

```
     AssertionError: expected belongsTo to have been called with arguments 'Dealer', {
  foreignKey: {
    type: [Function: Noop],
    allowNull: false,
    name: 'dealer_product_dpid'
  }
}
undefined '"Dealer"' 
{
  foreignKey: { type: [Function: Noop], allowNull: false, name: 'dealers_did' }
  foreignKey: {
    type: [Function: Noop],
    allowNull: false,
    name: 'dealer_product_dpid'
  }
}
```

It is saying `undefined '"Dealer"'`  Dealer my String is undefined. How can I solve this?

As for original Table the Dealer is the one that is associated with DealerProduct

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

All my steps were correct apart from

```
      const OtherModel = 'Dealer' // it doesn't matter what
      before(() => {
        DealerProduct.associate( { OtherModel }  )
      })
calledWith(OtherModel)
```

The calledWith cannot have a string parameter but the model Dealer instead.

So where I was doing:

```
const DealerProductModel = require('../../models/dealer-products-model');
    const DealerProduct = DealerProductModel(sequelize, dataTypes);
    const dealerProduct = new DealerProduct();
```

I should have imported the DealerModel as well so it should have been

```
const DealerProductModel = require('../../models/dealer-products-model');
const DealerModel = require('../../models/dealers-model');
    const DealerProduct = DealerProductModel(sequelize, dataTypes);
    const dealerProduct = new DealerProduct();
    const Dealer = DealerModel(sequelize, dataTypes);
    const dealer = new Dealer();
```

Then send that `const Dealer = DealerModel(sequelize, dataTypes);` in there like this:

```
    describe('check associations', () => {
      before(() => {
        DealerProduct.associate( { Dealer }  )
      })
      it('defined a belongsTo association with Dealer', () => {
        chai.expect(DealerProduct.belongsTo).to.have.been.calledWith(Dealer)
      })
    })
```